# Is there a way to get ID of particular email ID?

Tags: python, win32com

I'm creating bot to send emails in outlook. Bot works fine but I want to improve it. The goal is to send reminders to the particular user, who has already been contacted - As replay to the existing email. Everything will be automatized and the information (message id, number of reminders etc.) will be stored in sqlite database. I need to know if there is a way to get ID of the outlook message (As far as i know each message before being send has id assigned) or something equalivent. I've checked many sources and couldn't get the answer that would satisfy me. Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook's object model has the EntryID property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.entryid

you can find items with it using win32com:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

mailID = "00000000D6287E76248B24409DF..." #Abbreviated - these are very long, unique strings
email = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(mailID)
print(email)
```

If you need to find out, which email has what ID, you can iterate over a folder and get it like this:

```
folder2iterate = outlook.Folders("myemail@provider.com").folders("FolderName") #FolderName has to be localized to the language you are using. "Inbox" is not a universal name
for email in folder2iterate.Items:
    print(email, email.Sender, email.EntryID)
```